# Trying to make a table of variable columns/rows in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, charts, range

Here is all the applicable code that I'm having a hard time with (though part of a large program). I'm making an executive dashboard, and this data rolls up into a chart on a separate sheet looking at month-over-month utility usage. It is supposed to copy over a variable number of utilities from a variable number of months.

Integer m is the months (I'm using 3/March as my example), so from i=1 to 3 it's supposed to copy/paste the rows from the ns that is opened into ws. It keeps giving an error 1004, so I think I'm calling my ranges incorrectly, but I'm not sure how/why. In my code, the error is down in that For Loop, none of the lines seem to work

I need some sort of variable so that I can later roll it up into my chart. Here are some photos of what's supposed to come over (only the headers are coming over, which wasn't using the .Cell(). Also, if anyone knows the correct way to code my second to last line, please share (though not my primary challenge).

[image: Source Data]

[image]

```
fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.XLSX), *.XLSX", Title:="Select Trend Income Statement for " & os.Range("B2") & " " & os.Range("B3"))
If fNameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub

'We are opening and pulling data from the selected workbook, so lets turn off screen updating and get to work
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set nb = Workbooks.Open(fNameAndPath)
Set ns = nb.Sheets(1)
    m = Month(ws.Range("B1"))

'Build out the Utility Section
Let FindIt = "50100-000"
Set FoundCell = ns.Range("A:A").Find(What:=FindIt)
    fRow = FoundCell.Row + 1 'This will be the first Util GL
Let FindIt2 = "50199-999"
Set FoundCell2 = ns.Range("A:A").Find(What:=FindIt2)
    fRow2 = FoundCell2.Row - 1 ' This will be the last Util GL

ns.Range("B" & fRow - 1 & ":B" & fRow2 + 1).Copy 'Copy the header range
ws.Range("G16").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

For i = 1 To m
    Set cRange = ns.Range(ns.Cells(fRow, 2 + i), ns.Cells(fRow2, 2 + i))
    ns.Range(cRange).Copy
    Set pRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(17, 7 + i))
    ws.Range(pRange).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    ws.Range(Cells(15, 7 + i)).Formula = "=TEXT(i*30, mmmmm)"
Next i
```

Comment: After 2 more hours of research, it looks like using .Address() converts it to an A1 format that VBA reads easier. I'm going to flush it out with that to see if that works for my needs, and update if it works.

Comment: which line of the code did you get the error?

Comment: seems like you can just use a PivotTable or PowerPivot with filters

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble getting several parts of your code to work as it seems to be a snippet of a larger program.

I think what might be causing your issue is that you are using one Cells() in  some of your Range() calls. The Range() call returns a 1004 error when I tried providing it with only one Cells() object.

For example you use

```
'This throws 1004 error
ws.Range(ws.Cells(17 , 7 + i ))
```

Try to use something like this

```
ws.Cells(17 , 7 + i)
```

Also, you can use something like this

```
ws.Range("G17").Offset(0,i)
```

See if any of these works for your use case and produces the desired result.

Comment: This looks more like a comment than an answer.